# How to draw Proper path between nodes (1,0) and (2,3)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzpagenodes

```
\tikz[auto, thick] {
\node[state] (23) {$2,3$};
\node[state, right=of 23] (33) {$3,3$};
\node[state, below=of 33] (22) {$2,2$};
\node[state, below=of 23] (12) {$1,2$};
\node[state, below=of 22] (11) {$1,1$};
\node[state, below=of 12] (01) {$0,1$};
\node[state, below=of 11] (00) {$0,0$};
\node[state, right=of 00] (10) {$1,0$};
\path (23) edge[->, loop above] node {$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node {$\alpha$} (33)
           edge[->, bend right] node {$\delta$} (12)
      (33) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (22)
      (12) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (22)
           edge[->, bend right] node{$\delta$} (01)
      (22) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (11)  
      (01) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (11) 
      (11) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (00)  
      (00) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (10) 
      (10) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (23)                   
;}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not able to post the code properly! The code that I have written draws the corresponding diagram. How to bend the path from node (10) to (23) such that it goes from below (00) and from right of (01) and (12).

Answer (score 5):

Can you change state `(1,0)` position?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikz[auto, thick] {
\node[state] (23) {$2,3$};
\node[state, right=of 23] (33) {$3,3$};
\node[state, below=of 33] (22) {$2,2$};
\node[state, below=of 23] (12) {$1,2$};
\node[state, below=of 22] (11) {$1,1$};
\node[state, below=of 12] (01) {$0,1$};
\node[state, below=of 11] (00) {$0,0$};
\node[state, left=of 00] (10) {$1,0$};
\path (23) edge[->, loop above] node {$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node {$\alpha$} (33)
           edge[->, bend right] node {$\delta$} (12)
      (33) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (22)
      (12) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (22)
           edge[->, bend right] node{$\delta$} (01)
      (22) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (11)  
      (01) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (11) 
      (11) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (00)  
      (00) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (10) 
      (10) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, out=150, in=180] node{$\alpha$} (23)                   
;}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change the position of the `(1,0)` node, you can connect the line from `(10.south west)` to `(23.west)` and specify the angles and distance of the line such as `out=-135,in=180,distance=4cm`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikz[auto, thick] {
\node[state] (23) {$2,3$};
\node[state, right=of 23] (33) {$3,3$};
\node[state, below=of 33] (22) {$2,2$};
\node[state, below=of 23] (12) {$1,2$};
\node[state, below=of 22] (11) {$1,1$};
\node[state, below=of 12] (01) {$0,1$};
\node[state, below=of 11] (00) {$0,0$};
\node[state, right=of 00] (10) {$1,0$};
\path (23) edge[->, loop above] node {$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node {$\alpha$} (33)
           edge[->, bend right] node {$\delta$} (12)
      (33) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (22)
      (12) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (22)
           edge[->, bend right] node{$\delta$} (01)
      (22) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (11)  
      (01) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (11) 
      (11) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\delta$} (00)  
      (00) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
           edge[->, bend left] node{$\alpha$} (10) 
      (10) edge[->, loop above] node{$(1-\alpha-\delta)$} ()
      (10.south west)
           edge[->,red,out=-135,in=180,distance=4cm] node{$\alpha$} (23.west)     ;}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not tested but, is it necessary to force node anchors to `(10.south west)` and `(23.west)` with these `in` and `out` angles?

Comment: @Ignasi: You are correct, it is not necessary. The automatic computation works just fine.